# What's it to ______? (anyone/someone)

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, phrases

We know that the phrase: "what's it to someone?" is used to tell someone angrily that something does not concern them.

[**Example1**:](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/What%27s+it+to+you%3F)

> What's it to them what I do on the weekends? That's my time to do as I like!

[**Example 2**](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/What%27s+it+to+you%3F)

> A: "Do you mind if I do yoga in the living room?" 
> B: "Of course not! What's it to me?"

**My question:**

I wonder which choice below sounds idiomatic? If none of them works, then how shall I utter it properly in natural, everyday English?

> I wanna drop out. What's it to _______?
>
> a. anyone 
> b. anybody 
> c. someone 
> d. somebody

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an AmE speaker, I feel all options are both natural sounding and idiomatic. Although, this phrase is never really used too much as a much more direct and natural sounding phrase can be used:

> Mind your own business etc.

Although rude, it is used more often.

Answer (score -1):

None of them works because *What is it to me?* is a rhetorical question meaning *It's none of my business/it doesn't matter to me.* You can't really ask an unspecified person a question like that. You would have to say *What is it to you?* (plural) or *What business is it of anybody's?*

Comment: I disagree; there are plenty of examples of "What's it to anybody" in live usage, and it makes perfect sense.  For example, in [the NY Times, quoting a person](https://www.nytimes.com/1998/01/29/nyregion/our-towns-frozen-north-doesn-t-jump-for-hot-news.html), in [a 19th-century novel](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Indiscretion_of_the_Duchess/Chapter_8), in [a 1954 Richard Wright novel](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Savage_Holiday/-H-7DwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22what%27s+it+to+anybody%22&pg=PT182&printsec=frontcover).

Comment: Well, then may I ask you @stangdon to answer to this question. That would be much more helpful compared to a comment.